# Элемент скрывается не всегда

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Вот пример(упростил) http://jsfiddle.net/Alfox/22Lqh/

При наведении на первую ссылку текст в низу заменяется 
но при наведении на 2 и 3 он не заменяется а остаётся + дополняется новым.

Задумка вот в чём есть стандартный текст при наведении на блок он заменяется на другой.
псевдоклассы не предлагать так как блоки находятся в разных областях принтскрина (и разных родительских классах)

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Че-то у вас там напутано,

html:

```
<div class="hoverme" id="block1">Реальные сроки</div>
<div class="hoverme" id="block2">Высокое качество</div>
<div class="hoverme" id="block3">Понятная документация</div>
<p rel="block" class="hover">Текст которые сначало виден но потом должен убирастя</p>
<p rel="block1" class="hover">Текст номер 1</p>
<p rel="block2" class="hover">Текст номер 2</p>
<p rel="block3" class="hover">Текст номер 3</p>
```

css:

```
.hover {
    display:none;
}
```

js:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $hover = $('.hover');
    $('.hoverme').hover(

    function () {
        $hover.hide().filter('[rel="' + this.id + '"]').show();
    },

    function () {
        $hover.hide().first().show();
    }

    );
    $hover.first().show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22Lqh/1/

Comment: Огромное спасибо.